# 2 names for input name tags css

Tags: css, forms, radio-button

i have a problem with CSS & HTML. I want to make two different "width" per name tags. This box with X should be 40 pixels wide. The rest should be stand by 105 pixels. I have written as:

CSS:

```
input[name=xr] {
    max-width: 15px !important;
    color: #fff;
```

}

HTML:

```
<input type="radio xr" id="radio2" name="radios" value="false"><label for="radio2">X</label>
```

See my demo: http://jsfiddle.net/1zhoooco/3/

But it don't works, where is the problem now? Thanks for helping.

Greez from Germany.

Comment: Sorry, but `<input type="radio xr">` violates the html standard. You cannot simply change that. You probably want to add a _class: `<input type="radio" class="xr">` and use that is your css selectors...